# What is the best scrobbler for Last.fm for my iOS device?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation, last.fm

I would like to scrobble played tracks to [Last.fm](http://www.last.fm/) from my iPod touch. I currently use the official iTunes scrobbler, but it seems to drop data.

What are the best iOS scrobblers for a jailbroken and a non-jailbroken device? I can't download the official Last.fm app because of stupid geographical restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the new [ex.fm app](http://ex.fm/iphone), which does scrobble to last.fm for me. The ex.fm app is brand new, so the twitter integration is off and on, but last.fm scrobbling of the ex.fm streaming songs is working very reliably. It doesn't scrobble my iPod songs that are on the device yet - so I don't know if that's intended, a temporary service issue, or a bug needing a new build of the app.

Comment: Good find - but like you said, local songs aren't being scrobbled to Last.fm (yet?).

Answer (score 4):

Get [CloudScrob](http://www.cloudscrob.com).

Finally there is an app that ACTUALLY WORKS AND SCROBBLES CORRECTLY.

This app is the best scrobbler there is for iPhone, and I've tried a bunch of them. It scrobbles in batch mode after you've listened to a bunch of songs, and lets you preview and edit the list of songs before it submits them.

And you use the iPod app to play the songs. Unlike iScrob where you had to use that app to play the songs.

Answer (score 0):

Your local songs on your device should scrobble to last.fm if you're playing them through the exfm app and have the newest version of the app.

Comment: Hi Jessica, could you add the link to the *exfm* app you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

## [Track 8](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/track-8/id519363162?mt=8)

..is nice. It's a player based on the Metro UI of the Windows 8 and it supports last.fm s scrobbling.

The following is from the app description:

> ♪ Scrobble your tracks to Last.FM, and share "Now Playing" tweets right from Track 8.
>
> ♪ View background images of artists from Last.fm

Answer (score 0):

You can try my app **[QuietScrob](http://quietscrob.droppages.com)**, it's only for iOS 7 but scrobbles in background.

Comment: AD does tolerate a certain amount of self-promotion, but please be open about it (see this [FAQ entry](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) for details).

Comment: @patrix oh, sure

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a way to Scrobble from the official Google Play Music app. It's still a work in progress and it requires a Jailbroken iPhone, but it works!

https://github.com/octalmage/LastGoogle